# Where can I ask a question about the money-value of an Access Database?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I'm developing an Access front-end Database for one of the largest Hospitals in my area. Currently, this Hospital is using Excel spreadsheet and employs a person to manually find replacements for Doctors and Nurses. It takes them about 15 minutes to find each replacement. The query that I've built takes about 1 second to find the replacement. The Database is fully customized, with a over 20 forms (to perform a search, add a new contact, change a contact's information, schedule availability dates, etc) I've also had to create the whole back-end SQL database, as everything before was located in disorganized excel worksheets.

My question is: Where can I get information and feedback for the value of this database? The Hospital has confirmed that they are willing to pay me for the custom build database, but I'm not sure what it's value is (and I don't know if the Hospital understands its value either).

I've been working on the project sporadically, and in the process have been teaching myself Access and VBA, and so can say that I've probably worked a solid 3 weeks on the database itself.

I use StackOverflow to ask a lot of programming questions, and I know that this questions is not suitable for that site.

Many thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for how to bill your client appropriately... that's probably going to be off topic for all sites across the network.

The usual way to bill for stuff like this is to calculate the time it took you to build the solution, and multiply that with an appropriate hourly rate.

There are resources that help you with determining the right hourly rate for independent IT professionals - I would start looking at them first. If all else fails, try to find out what other contractors in your area charge. You'll get a broad range of rates, but it might help you to set your own rate depending on how much experience you have, and how quick a worker you are.

Comment: Yeah... I was pretty sure that SE was the wrong place to post a question like this. worth a try though. Thanks for your reply.